# Uploading debug symbols to Crashlytics without GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: python, ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I'm working on integrating Firebase Crashlytics (as well as analytics) into my team's app. Due to various reasons, we're manually configuring an `FIROptions` object and calling [`-[FIROptions initWithGoogleAppId:GCMSenderID:]`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIROptions#-initwithgoogleappid:gcmsenderid:), configuring the properties we need, and then calling  [`-[FIRApp configureWithName:options:]`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIRApp#+configurewithname:options:) from there. This is working great, and I can see analytics working and crashes get uploaded to our Crashlytics dashboard

However, I can't get the build phase to upload the generated `.dSYM` files to succeed. The suggested script is to add this as the last step in the build process:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"
```

That phase should also be passed the `Info.plist` as an input file. However, when I remove the `GoogleService-Info.plist` from our bundle, the build fails with this error: `Could not get GMP_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment`

This makes sense to me, because it's still looking for the `GoogleService-Info.plist` I removed. I wrote my own Python script to attempt to generate a temporary .plist file from our data, which currently looks like this:

```
import subprocess
import tempfile
import plistlib
import pathlib

firebase_app_id: str = "<# OUR FIREBASE APP ID HERE #>"

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_folder, open(pathlib.Path(temp_folder) / "GoogleService-Info.plist", "wb") as temp_plist:
    plistlib.dump({"GOOGLE_APP_ID": firebase_app_id}, temp_plist)
    subprocess.run([f"{os.environ['PODS_ROOT']}/Fabric/upload-symbols", "--google-service-plist", temp_plist.name, "--build-phase", "--debug"], check=True)
```

Running this script as a build phase generates the following error: `Unable to read GoogleService-Info.plist at path /var/folders/4g/_p4pgc5d485gtcn_3dtys4y00000gn/T/tmp7m7r_0zj/GoogleService-Info.plist`

I've also tried generating a normal `NamedTemporaryFile`, but that results in the same issue. Not running the script in build phase mode and manually passing the platform and symbol files results in the first error I got about the `GMP_APP_ID`. How can I make a build phase to automatically upload our debugging symbols to Crashlytics, without having to add a `GoogleService-Info.plist` to our project?

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool that upload dSYM files to Crashlytics without anything.

Use it to solve your problem:
https://github.com/prsolucoes/fabric-upload-dsym

In **"dist"** folder you can find your correct version depending of your OS.

- Windows
- macOS
- Linux

---

**HOW TO USE**

```
fabric-upload-dsym --bundleid=[YOUR-APP-BUNDLE] --fabricapikey=[YOUR-FABRIC-API-KEY] --file=[ZIPPED-DSYM-FILE]
```

Replace in command with your info, example:

```
[YOUR-APP-BUNDLE] = com.prsolucoes.myapp
[YOUR-FABRIC-API-KEY] = 12xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbf
[ZIPPED-DSYM-FILE] = /tmp/yourapp/dsym.zip
```

Thanks.